# How to make a Truncated normal distribution in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, normal-distribution

I want to create a **Truncated normal distribution**(that is Gaussian distribution with a range) in PyTorch.
I want to be able to change the mean, std, and range.
Is there a PyTorch method for that?

Comment: This seems to be helpful, you can basically replicate the equivalent scipy version: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/implementing-truncated-normal-initializer/4778/20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `torch.nn.init.trunc_normal_`.

Description as given [Here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a40812de534b42fcf0eb57a5cecbfdc7a70100cf/torch/nn/init.py#L153):

> Fills the input Tensor with values drawn from a truncated
> normal distribution. The values are effectively drawn from the
> normal distribution :math:`\mathcal{N}(\text{mean}, \text{std}^2)`
> with values outside :math:`[a, b]` redrawn until they are within
> the bounds. The method used for generating the random values works
> best when :math:`a \leq \text{mean} \leq b`.

Answer (score 0):

I know the best solution must be `torch.nn.init.trunc_normal_`.
But the problem is that the func cannot be called.
May we can create this func by copying src code.

```
def _no_grad_trunc_normal_(tensor, mean, std, a, b):
    # Method based on https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf
    def norm_cdf(x):
        # Computes standard normal cumulative distribution function
        return (1. + math.erf(x / math.sqrt(2.))) / 2.

    if (mean < a - 2 * std) or (mean > b + 2 * std):
        warnings.warn("mean is more than 2 std from [a, b] in nn.init.trunc_normal_. "
                      "The distribution of values may be incorrect.",
                      stacklevel=2)

    with torch.no_grad():
        # Values are generated by using a truncated uniform distribution and
        # then using the inverse CDF for the normal distribution.
        # Get upper and lower cdf values
        l = norm_cdf((a - mean) / std)
        u = norm_cdf((b - mean) / std)

        # Uniformly fill tensor with values from [l, u], then translate to
        # [2l-1, 2u-1].
        tensor.uniform_(2 * l - 1, 2 * u - 1)

        # Use inverse cdf transform for normal distribution to get truncated
        # standard normal
        tensor.erfinv_()

        # Transform to proper mean, std
        tensor.mul_(std * math.sqrt(2.))
        tensor.add_(mean)

        # Clamp to ensure it's in the proper range
        tensor.clamp_(min=a, max=b)
        return tensor

def trunc_normal_(tensor: Tensor, mean: float = 0., std: float = 1., a: float = -2., b: float = 2.) -> Tensor:
    r"""Fills the input Tensor with values drawn from a truncated
    normal distribution. The values are effectively drawn from the
    normal distribution :math:`\mathcal{N}(\text{mean}, \text{std}^2)`
    with values outside :math:`[a, b]` redrawn until they are within
    the bounds. The method used for generating the random values works
    best when :math:`a \leq \text{mean} \leq b`.

    Args:
        tensor: an n-dimensional `torch.Tensor`
        mean: the mean of the normal distribution
        std: the standard deviation of the normal distribution
        a: the minimum cutoff value
        b: the maximum cutoff value

    Examples:
        >>> w = torch.empty(3, 5)
        >>> nn.init.trunc_normal_(w)
    """
    return _no_grad_trunc_normal_(tensor, mean, std, a, b)
```